# How to get the token prices from the uniswap v3 pools?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, decentralized-exchange, uniswapv3, price

I have to write the solidity code to fetch the prices of token pairs from the uniswap v3 pools but I have no idea how to get the prices of the token pairs from the uniswap v3 pools to my smart contract.Im happy if you can share some resources or help me to fetch the prices.Thank you!

Comment: You can find [some tutorials here for reading Uniswap v3 prices](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/tutorials/index.html).